# Hibernate EntityGraph on @Basic fields does not work as expected

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitygraph

It seems that Hibernate ignores any @Basic field specified in javax.persistence.fetchgraph and always loads the whole object until we explicitly define the field as @Basic(fecth=LAZY).
However the JPA 2.1 standard says:

> To specify a fetch graph, set the javax.persistence.fetchgraph property when you execute an EntityManager.find or query operation. A fetch graph consists of only the fields explicitly specified in the EntityGraph instance, and **ignores the default entity graph settings**.

The problem is that I do not want to set all fields to LAZY load by default since I only need partial objects in some particular cases on massive data fetches for UI. Is there any work-around for this case when I can dynamically specify what to load?

EclipseLink works with fetchgraph as expected.

P.S. Hibernate 5.3.1.Final, bytecode enhancement made with hibernate-gradle-plugin:5.3.1.Final:

```
hibernate {
    enhance {
        enableLazyInitialization= true
        enableDirtyTracking = true
        enableAssociationManagement = true
        enableExtendedEnhancement = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a Hibernate's bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8776